# MVC Asp.Net: Dynamic Variables and Extension Methods in Razor Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to print a link in my razor view with the item's id encoded. So i've made an extension method to encode an int to a base64 string.

The code is the next:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Item", "Delete", new{ idItem = item.IdItem.EncodeTo64() })
```

The **item.IdItem** is an int, but as i am working with dynamic variables, the **EncodeTo64()** method is not recognized as an extension method of the int variable. And it returns an error:

> 'int' doesn't have a definition for 'EncodeTo64'

So, i've found a solution: cast the dynamic variable, like this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete Item", "Delete", new{ idItem = ((int)item.IdItem).EncodeTo64() })
```

It works, but i don't like this solution... do you know any way for avoiding this cast and make it work?

Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This is the extension method:

```
public static string EncodeTo64(this int number)
{
    byte[] encoded = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(number.ToString());
    return Convert.ToBase64String(encoded);
}
```

Comment: Is there any reason that you can't use EncodeTo64() BEFORE you pass the model to the view?

Comment: Can you provide the extension method code?

Comment: In fact, I think you *should* be encoding it before passing it to the view.

Comment: What's wrong with casting? I always do this and have yet to see any adverse effects.

Comment: @DavidL & danielrozo : I don't agree, because it is my item's class from my model, and it shouldn't take care of how the web handle the parameters and stuff. The Id is a number, because in the real world the id of the item is a number too.

Comment: @JeradRose i've added the extension method. Check it out

Comment: @Mansfield i don't think it's wrong, but i don't like to cast pointless

Comment: @ArielScherman You are trying to call type specific methods inside of an anonymous function declaration that does not yet have knowledge of the business rules of its members, whereas doing it in the controller or a view model makes perfect sense, since it has knowledge of the member's type and any applicable business rules.  Once again, you could solve all your problems by calling EncodeTo64() somewhere other than the view.

Answer (score 2):

This can't be done with a `dynamic` type because the compiler will never be able to infer which extension method to use.

Under the hood the compiler will turn this:

```
myVar.EncodeTo64();
```

Into this:

```
MyStaticClass.EncodeTo64(myVar);
```

It has to have this information at compile time, but because you are using a `dynamic`, you are explicitly telling the compiler to wait until runtime to work out which call to make.

**You have three options:**

1. Use a strongly typed model
2. Add a property/method that does it for you
3. Live with the cast

Comment: I don't want to change the model because what i said above, so i think i'll live with the cast.

Thanks for your help!